# IE.navigate2 fails with protected mode off

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-8, excel-2010

I'm automating IE8 from Excel VBA (Excel 2010, Windows 7)

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate2 URL
```

If URL is a website in a zone where IE protected mode is on, everything is fine.

If URL is a website in a zone where IE protected mode is off, the script fails (IE becomes automatically visible, IE object is lost in VBA - automation error).

Is there any way to enable navigate2 in zones with protected mode off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want to do is create an instance of IE running at Medium Integrity, and navigate that. Typically, you'd do that by using CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium). Currently, there's no ProgID that points at this CLSID, however, it you can easily create one:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetExplorer.ApplicationMedium]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetExplorer.ApplicationMedium\CLSID]
@="{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}"
```

You can then invoke this object thusly:

```
CreateObject("InternetExplorer.ApplicationMedium")
```

I explain a bit more fully over here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/internet-explorer-automation-protected-mode-lcie-default-integrity-level-medium.aspx

Comment: Wow, I've spent so much time with this issue and this seemed to solve it. I'm curious though - my startmediumtab registry entry is pointing at CLSID {9af8cd33-7aae-4cc2-b00a-835f6721e3c2}, however adding the above entry (pointing at a different GIUD) appears to work. Also the `new:` syntax below threw errors no matter what I tried.

Answer (score 9):

Getting InternetExplorer.ApplicationMedium by CLSID:

```
Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
```

Comment: In VB6 why do I get IE object EMPTY after this above code? Does the Registry# differ machine to machine? If yes, how can I create a vb6 app that will run on different machines?

Comment: @MehdiAnis: No, the CLSID should be the same. Does Eric's code work for you? This GetObject call might be scripting specific and might not work in VB6. (You also need to be running on Vista+ with UAC and Protected Mode IE on probably)

Comment: The app I was working on runs on both XP w/IE6 and W7 w/IE8 machines. I was getting NULL in my in XP machines. And I used an IF statement to see if NULL to use existing code that we know works for XP. For W7 machines value will not be NULL and ELSE part will create IE Instance in Medium Security. It works perfectly. Thanks, your instinct is correct - I needed Vista or newer OS.

Comment: I tried this syntax in VBScript and got errors no matter what I tried.