# Setting 'New InternetExplorer' generates automation error: -2125463506 (8150002e)

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code to login to a website. Sometimes it works, but other times I get

> automation error: 2125463506 (8150002e).

I have read a number of posts related to this topic, tried a number of different methods and still can't get it to work.

My OS is Windows 10. In Windows 7 I didnt get this error.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub Repsol1()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim form As HTMLFormElement
MyURL = "https://login.repsol.com/es/Landing/AuthnPage?returnUrl=https://www.repsol.com/es_es/"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.Navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document

Do While HTMLDoc.getElementById("gigya-login-form") Is Nothing
    DoEvents
Loop

Set form = HTMLDoc.getElementById("gigya-login-form")

form.all.UserName.Value = "XXXXX@XXXXX"
form.all.Password.Value = "XXXXX"

form.getElementsByClassName("gigya-input-submit")(0).Click

Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://www.repsol.com/es_es/aplicaciones/SO/WebEESS/default.aspx?usuario=XXXXX"
End With

End Sub
```

[image: Automation error]
[image: Debug error]

Comment: The same issue seems to have been addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909226/ie-navigate2-fails-with-protected-mode-off

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use *Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorerMedium*. IE updated its security within the browser.